# Failed to connect to your database server

Tags: drupal

I do not understand what is wrong. It's as if all the data is correct.

> Resolve all issues below to continue the installation. For help configuring your database server, see the installation handbook, or contact your hosting provider.
>
> - Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.
>   > - Is the database server running?
> - Does the database exist or does the database user have sufficient privileges to create the database?
> - Have you entered the correct database name?
> - Have you entered the correct username and password?
> - Have you entered the correct database hostname and port number?

[image]

`I take data from the ".env" file (DB_NAME=... DB_USER=... DB_PASSWORD=...)`

Comment: The install page does not know about your environment variables. Is your problem that you enter the database details and it does not connect? Or are you expecting this page to pick up your environment variables (which it wont)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Drupal does not use .env file by default. Instead you have to copy `default.settings.php` to `settings.php` under web/sites/default directory.

There you have a `$database` array in which you can provide the above information. Or you just create settings.php file as mentioned above with required permission and then simply put in your DB credentials in the installation wizard (Your screenshot). Drupal will automatically update the settings.php file.

Once the installation is over, you can provide 444 permission bits to settings.php for security.

Answer (score 0):

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'enxport',
      'username' => 'admin',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '3306',
      'prefix' => 'enxport',
    ),
  ),
);
```